# Can not get values from a form in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the values of the different inputs of this form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="form_newCours">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="discipline">Matiere:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="discipline" placeholder="Matiere">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" align="left">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="datetimepicker">Date:</label>
            <div class="input-group col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datetimepicker"/>
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox" id="creneau_regulier"> Ce creneau regulier</label>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="btn-newCours">Ajouter</button>
            </div>
        </div>
 </form>
```

And I have this JS code where I try to get the values of the inputs:

```
$('#btn-newCours').on('click', function(e) {

    // this will stop the form from submitting normally and let you handle it yourself with the following code:
    e.preventDefault();

    // YK: Bellow is my code
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify($('#form_newCours').serializeObject());
    console.log($('#form_newCours').serialize());
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: jsonString,
      url: "/cours/",
      contentType: "application/json"
    });
  });
```

The function is called, but the variable jsonString is empty. I'm not so familiar with JS, but can the additionnal div between the form and input cause problems ?

**Edit**:

P.S. I'm using a plugin for serializeObject().

Comment: There is no `serializeObject()` method, unless you're using a plugin. Just provide the `data` property the result of `$('#form_newCours').serialize()` and remove the `contentType` and your code should work.

Comment: "The function is called, but the variable jsonString is empty" — How do you know? You aren't examining it anywhere in that code.

Comment: I am using Firebug, and it shows that the Post requests has an empty data.

Comment: @Spider — Then take a few steps back. console.log the actual value of `jsonString`. console.log the return value of `serializeObject()`

Comment: @Spider first give the "name" to all input element and after i think that work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add name attribute to your inputs.

Comment: Thank you. I first thought that "id"s were enough, but they should all have a "name" attribute as you (and other) suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Add name attribute to your inputs

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="form_newCours">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="discipline">Matiere:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="discipline" placeholder="Matiere" name="discipline">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" align="left">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="datetimepicker">Date:</label>
            <div class="input-group col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datetimepicker" name="datetimepicker"/>
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox" id="creneau_regulier" name="creneau_regulier"> Ce creneau regulier</label>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="btn-newCours">Ajouter</button>
            </div>
        </div>
 </form>
```

**Note :** If you are using jquery-serialize-object Plugin, you can replace

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify($('#form_newCours').serializeObject());
```

with

```
var jsonString = $('#form_newCours').serializeJSON();
```